# Tabular vertically centered with MusiXTeX

Tags: tables, musixtex

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  Type & Qualification & Notes & Graphie & Nbr de demi-tons & Nbr de
  demi-tons diatonique\\
  \hline
  \multirow{5}{*}{Seconde}  & Majeur & Do~-~Ré &
  \hspace{-100pt}
\scalebox{0.7}{
  \begin{music}
    \nobarnumbers
    \setclef10
    \startextract
      \notes  \qa c \qa d \en
    \endextract
  \end{music}}
  \hspace{-100pt}
                            & 2 & 0\\
  \cline{2-6}
                            & Majeur & Ré~-~Mi &
  \hspace{-100pt}
\scalebox{0.7}{
  \begin{music}
    \nobarnumbers
    \setclef10
    \startextract
      \notes  \qa d \qa e \en
    \endextract
  \end{music}}
  \hspace{-100pt}
                            & 2 & 0\\
  \cline{2-6}
                            & Mineur & Mi~-~Fa &
  \hspace{-100pt}
\scalebox{0.7}{
  \begin{music}
    \nobarnumbers
    \setclef10
    \startextract
      \notes  \qa e \qa f \en
    \endextract
  \end{music}}
  \hspace{-100pt}
                            & 1 & 1\\
  \cline{2-6}
                            & Majeur & Fa~-~Sol &
  \hspace{-100pt}
\scalebox{0.7}{
  \begin{music}
    \nobarnumbers
    \setclef10
    \startextract
      \notes  \qa f \qa g \en
    \endextract
  \end{music}}
  \hspace{-100pt}
                            & 2 & 0\\
  \cline{2-6}
                            & Majeur & Sol~-~La &
  \hspace{-100pt}
\scalebox{0.7}{
  \begin{music}
    \nobarnumbers
    \setclef10
    \startextract
      \notes  \qa g \qa h \en
    \endextract
  \end{music}}
  \hspace{-100pt}
                            & 2 & 0\\
  \hline
        \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which produce:
[image: Table 1]

As we can see, in this table, the text is not vertically centered. I see other similar questions, but they always use `p{...}`, `m{...}` or `b{...}` arguments. I tried this and it centers vertically, but it's no more horizontally centered, and the first line has more height.

So, how can I get everything centered horizontally and vertically, while keeping the first line the same size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

like this?

[image]

with use of the package `adjustbox` and defining new command for shorter code:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcommand\MusiC[1]{\adjustbox{trim=145pt 0pt 140pt 0pt, valign=c}%
            {\begin{music}
                \nobarnumbers
                \setclef10
                \startextract
                  \notes  #1
                \endextract
              \end{music}}
                    }


\begin{document}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  Type & Qualification & Notes & Graphie & Nbr de demi-tons & Nbr de
  demi-tons diatonique\\
  \hline
\multirow{18}{*}{Seconde}
    & Majeur    & Do~-~Ré   & \MusiC{\qa c \qa d \en} & 2 & 0\\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Majeur    & Ré~-~Mi   & \MusiC{\qa d \qa e \en} & 2 & 0\\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Mineur    & Mi~-~Fa   & \MusiC{\qa e \qa f \en} & 1 & 1\\
    \cline{2-6}
    & Majeur    & Fa~-~Sol  & \MusiC{\qa f \qa g \en} & 2 & 0\\
  \cline{2-6}
  & Majeur  & Sol~-~La      & \MusiC{\qa g \qa h \en} & 2 & 0\\
  \hline
        \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```